# How to overwrite a file if it already exists in dropbox?

Tags: java, android, dropbox

I am uploading a file in dropbox by this method:

```
public void upload() {

        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString() + "/write.txt");
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            Entry newEntry = mDBApi.putFile("/write.txt", inputStream,
                    file.length(), null, null);
            Log.i("DbExampleLog", "The uploaded file's rev is: " + newEntry.rev);
        } catch (DropboxUnlinkedException e) {
            // User has unlinked, ask them to link again here.
            Log.e("DbExampleLog", "User has unlinked.");
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            Log.e("DbExampleLog", "Something went wrong while uploading.");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("DbExampleLog", "File not found.");
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

but when already this file exists in the folder then the file get renamed to write(1).txt
but I want that if the file already exists in the dropbox share folder then it will be replaced. What should I do now?

Comment: did u tried `file.exists()` function

Comment: No , but if this works then what should I do to overwrite the previous?

Comment: @reiley `File.exists()` won't work across a network to Dropbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mDBApi.putFileOverwrite` instead of `mDBApi.putFile`